# How does thunderbird know which emails have been read? X-Mozilla-Status wrong

Tags: linux, thunderbird

I'm trying to write a script to check how many unread messages there are in a certain mailbox. I thought thunderbird (icedove, I'm running debian jessie) used the X-Mozilla-Status header to keep track of this. Indeed, for my POP mail accounts checking whether the last digit of the X-Mozilla-Status header is 0 tells me whether or not the message has been read, and correctly gives the number of unread messages.

However, for my IMAP accounts, the X-Mozilla-Status flag seems to have no relationship to whether or not I have read the email. Brand new emails come in marked with a 1 in the last spot, and some don't have the flag at all.

My end goal is to have something like

```
grep -c "X-Mozilla-Status: [0-9]\{3\}0" $MAIL_FOLDERS | grep -o '[0-9]\+$' | xargs echo
```

that actually works with IMAP accounts.

Answer (score 1):

The read status is sometimes kept in the .MSF file associated with the folder.

The file has the [Mork format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%28file_format%29) and the read status is in column "flags".

You can get the info as XML with https://github.com/KevinGoodsell/mork-converter/

Answer (score -1):

IMAP is having it's own status flags to see, which mails are marked as being read. Depending on your langauge you are using for your script, you will finde solutions at SE-network.

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: Just grepping the local mail folder will not be enough to see which mails have been read, as the server is keeping the master track and not your local Thundebird mail archive -> webmail

Comment: But thunderbird knows which messages i've read locally even when I'm offline. It must be keeping track of this information somewhere and just syncing it when it talks to the server.